# Debug Zend Framework 1 test failure

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, testing, frameworks

Running this in my test suite:

```
$this->dispatch('/default/company/infobox/id/355');
$this->assertResponseCode(200);
```

Fails:

```
1) CompanyControllerTest::testCompanyInfobox
Failed asserting response code "200"
Was "500"
```

How can I find out what the output of the page was? When visiting the url in my browser, there is no response 500...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Zend_Test, you can use:

```
$this->getResponse()->getBody();
```

to get the output of the page.  Most of the time, if you get a '500' code when testing but not in your browser, it's a problem in your configurations.  Doing an echo on that line should help you find the error.

Comment: An echo doesn't work when using phpunit. It is swallowed somewhere. How can I disable this?

Comment: Ah, need to echo before the assert :) Thanks!